# Rails -- "remember me" capability

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, remember-me

I am having trouble understanding the implementation of "Remember Me" in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.  He creates a SessionsHelper module with methods for signing in, containing the following:

```
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
        current_user = user
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        return @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
    end

    private
        def user_from_remember_token
            #passes array of length two as a parameter -- first slot contains ID,
            #second contains SALT for encryption
            User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
        end

        def remember_token
            #ensures return of a double array in the event that
            #cookies.signed[:remember_token] is nil.
            cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
        end

end
```

*NOTE: The* `authenticate_with_salt` *method in the User model finds the user by the first parameter (the id) and if the user is defined and its salt is equivalent to the second parameter (the salt) then the user is returned, otherwise nil is returned.*

I am having trouble understanding why we go to such lengths to test if the user has already been signed in:

In the event that the user is signed in, `@current_user` is already defined by the `sign_in` method and therefore the ||= in the `current_user` method is meaningless.

In the event that the user is not signed in, the ||= operator in the `current_user` method returns the value returned by the `user_from_remember_token` method, but since cookies.signed[:remember_token] would be nil, `User.authenticate_with_salt` would be passed the [nil,nil] argument and would return nil, and therefore, the `current_user` method would return nil.

In short, if the `current_user` method is returning @current_user if it is defined and nil otherwise, wouldn't it be much simpler to just use the conventional accessor method:

```
def current_user
    return @current_user
end
```

Michael Hartl's book says that doing this would be useless because the user's sign in status would be forgotten.  Why would that be the case???  Can someone please explain why we do not do this and instead use the much more intricate version posted above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
return @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
```

is a form of lazy initialization to avoid initializing the `@current_user` variable until it is actually needed.  `@current_user` will never be initialized the first time this function is called, but it will have a value on each successive call (assuming `user_from_remember_token` returns something other than nil).

He could have written

```
def current_user
  return user_from_remember_token
end
```

This code will always initialize the current user to whatever it reads from the cookie.  This would behave correctly, but he probably wanted to avoid repeatedly reading the cookie, so he does it once and stores it in a variable.

He cannot do

```
def current_user
  return @current_user
end
```

because the @current_user variable does not persist across page requests.  After the page renders and is sent back to the client, the @current_user variable is destroyed and its value is forgotten.

Hope this helps. Look into maintaining state in web applications for more information on why it's necessary to jump through these hoops.

Answer (score 2):

`sign_in` is only called when you actually sign in using the login form. After that you have to set the current user using the cookie values for each request.

So when the user is signed in and opens a page, first time `current_user` is called it will populate the `@current_user` instance variable and use it for further `current_user` calls.

Comment: But once @current_user is set by sign_in, isn't it there to stay?  Like why can't we just use an instance variable @current_user instead of a cookie?  What is the main difference between them?

Comment: Like Michael Venable's answer says: "@current_user variable does not persist across page requests". So first time you are using the `current_user` method in a page request, you need to get the user information from the cookie.